# Osgi ServiceMix ClassCastException

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am having trouble with ServiceMix 5.5.2.

I have a bundle A that contain a class `test.java.Root.class` and after update of other bundle in ServiceMix my bundle A says:

```
ClassCastException : class test.java.Root can t be cast to test.java.Root
```

It the same class...

I know that the real problem is that this class was loading twice by different ClassLoader but I don't know why and when: the class is inside the jar and the package is not exported.

I have done refresh on the bundle but nothing work. Only a ServiceMix restart work :(

How can I find (before restarting and avoid restarting) all references of the class and where reference are still possibly in use?

Does ServiceMix propose Karaf command to see this?

Comment: To make OSGi bundle updates and refreshes work you have to take care that a bundle shuts down all threads and deletes all references to classes that could prevent cleanup of the classloader. Can you maybe post the code of the bundle?

Comment: No i can t put code of the bundle,but how can i see reference of the class simply? Does servicemix have something simple to do this?or i need to use some tools to find reference in jvm? How i want is how to find a bundle still installed and present in cache but not show with list comand...:(